# UPS API throws an "Invalid Shipment content Value" error for US country

Tags: xml, ups-api

I am using UPS API for CANADA and USA countries, the shipment origin will always be Canada.
The below is a request I am passing to get the UPS rates and to get an Estimated Arrival Time. If I pass the below request parameters for Canada address it works fine in response, but if I pass an US address in UPS API request parameters it throws an `Invalid Shipment Contents Value` error.

Here are the UPS API **Request** and its **Response** that works fine for the Canada address, but does not work for any US addresses:

**Request**

```
<AccessRequest xml:lang="en-US">    
  <AccessLicenseNumber>******</AccessLicenseNumber> 
  <UserId>*****</UserId>    
  <Password>*****</Password>    
</AccessRequest><?xml version="1.0"?>   
<RatingServiceSelectionRequest xml:lang="en-US">    
  <Request> 
    <TransactionReference>  
      <CustomerContext>Rating and Service</CustomerContext> 
      <XpciVersion>1.0</XpciVersion>    
    </TransactionReference> 
    <RequestAction>Rate</RequestAction> 
    <RequestOption>Shoptimeintransit</RequestOption>    
  </Request>    
  <PickupType>  
          <Code>01</Code>   
          <Description>Regular Daily Pickup</Description>   
  </PickupType> 
  <Shipment>      <Shipper><ShipperNumber>****</ShipperNumber>      <Address>   
          <City>Scarborough</City>  
          <PostalCode>M1G 0A6</PostalCode>  
          <CountryCode>CA</CountryCode> 
          <StateProvinceCode>ON</StateProvinceCode> 
      </Address>    
    </Shipper>  
    <ShipTo>    
      <Address> 
          <PostalCode>14304</PostalCode>    
          <CountryCode>US</CountryCode> 
          <ResidentialAddress>02</ResidentialAddress>   
          <StateProvinceCode>NY</StateProvinceCode>      </Address> 
    </ShipTo>   
    <ShipFrom>  
      <Address> 
          <PostalCode>M1G 0A6</PostalCode>  
          <CountryCode>CA</CountryCode> 
          <StateProvinceCode>ON</StateProvinceCode> 
      </Address>    
    </ShipFrom> 
    <DeliveryTimeInformation>   
    <PackageBillType>03</PackageBillType>   
</DeliveryTimeInformation>  
    <Package>   
      <PackagingType>   
        <Code>00</Code> 
      </PackagingType>  
      <PackageWeight>   
        <UnitOfMeasurement> 
          <Code>LBS</Code>  
        </UnitOfMeasurement>    
        <Weight>0.2</Weight>    
      </PackageWeight>  
    </Package>  
    <ShipmentTotalWeight>   
    <UnitOfMeasurement> 
        <Code>LBS</Code>    
    </UnitOfMeasurement>    
    <Weight>0.2</Weight>    
    </ShipmentTotalWeight><RateInformation><NegotiatedRatesIndicator/></RateInformation>      </Shipment>   
    </RatingServiceSelectionRequest>
```

**RESPONSE**

```
<RatingServiceSelectionResponse>
    <Response>
        <TransactionReference>
            <CustomerContext>Rating and Service</CustomerContext>
            <XpciVersion>1.0</XpciVersion>
        </TransactionReference>
        <ResponseStatusCode>0</ResponseStatusCode>
        <ResponseStatusDescription>Failure</ResponseStatusDescription>
        <Error>
            <ErrorSeverity>Hard</ErrorSeverity>
            <ErrorCode>111549</ErrorCode>
            <ErrorDescription>Invalid Shipment Contents Value.</ErrorDescription>
        </Error>
    </Response>
</RatingServiceSelectionResponse>
```

What am I doing wrong in the above request for the US address?

Comment: Can you provide test access credentials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the solution for my problem from this source.

https://medium.com/@soni.manthan0/ups-api-get-estimated-delivery-date-456f00e70742

As per the above link, it says it requires to add new `<InvoiceLineTotal>` section in `<shipment>` section and `<city>` is required in `<ShipTo>` section.

Answer (score 1):

It seems pretty frequent error when using this API.
I did some googling and these are some links with info I've found.

https://twitter.com/shippo/status/952965049840054272

https://www.ups.com/lk/en/help-center/sri/apishippingerror.page

There is also this guide, maybe it could be usefull.

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiiy_u244v1AhXN57sIHUW0A1cQFnoECBkQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fforum.opencart.com%2Fdownload%2Ffile.php%3Fid%3D33732&usg=AOvVaw0LKV9JkS-OTzi0nBgvpjnI

Comment: Thanks but I found the solution and I post the answer